# Flash, SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF cannot access Internet URL

Tags: flash, security

There is a number of flashfiles that my application is very much dependent of, and unfortunately, when i am trying to run my app on a server different from the one we have been developing it on, i get the following error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///C|/Users/user/Desktop/flash/flash.swf cannot access Internet URL rtmp://192.168.1.33/rtmp
```

I tried adding the `crossdomain.xml` file to the server, however, it doesn't work. Is there anything i can do to allow that file to access that stream?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is what worked for me: adding the following `crossdomain.xml`:

`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>`

Even though it is not quite secure in my case.

Comment: where i need to add this file in SWF source location?