# how to embed symboles IDs stored into external swf file into my swf app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder, flash

My app will run on desktop, I am trying to embed a swf file, to use all its symbols IDs,
I tried to load it, but, I get this error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file:///D|/my%20projects/bin/app.swf cannot access local resource file:///D|/my%20projects/bin/graphicsDLL.xml. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
    at flash.net::URLStream/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/load()
```

so, I tried to embed each symbol's ID like this:

```
[Embed(source="../../../swc/components.swf", mimeType="gxBattery")]
public var gxBattery:Class;
```

but, I get this error:

```
D:\my projects\src\com\components\Battery.as(34): col: 9: Error: no transcoder registered for mimeType 'gxBattery'
```

But, I am sure that I have a movie clip with ID `gxBattery`

The question is, how can I overcome the security problem in the first error above ?
Loading swf file will make all symboles IDs available to my app, which is what I need.

Also, how can I use the symbols IDs by embedding them ? Can I embed them all at once ?

Comment: Probably getting the error because the swf your loading is trying to load an xml file, but the swf was exported to use network resources only

Comment: yes I am trying to load xml file, shall I load swf file directly? will this work?

Comment: do you have the .fla (source file) for the swf your loading?

Comment: If you do, then look at my answer for this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093375/flash-securityerror-error-2028-local-with-filesystem-swf-cannot-access-inter/12096458#12096458  Just the opposite, instead of Network only, choose local only

Comment: I will try to do so thanks, I will try to find the .fla

Comment: If you don't have access to the .fla, you use adobe's tool to change the swf's security policy:  http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#lcu

Comment: adobe's tool ? I will try it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `mimeType` but `symbol`:

```
[Embed(source="../../../swc/components.swf", symbol="gxBattery")]
public var gxBattery:Class;
```